# The meaning of a symbol in Monotone operator

Tags: optimization, notation, monotone-functions, hessian-matrix, monotone-operator-theory

I'm learning monotone operator these days and can't figure out the meaning of the symbol.

If you know the symbol please tell me.

Thanks for your time!

## $$\nabla^2 f(x) \succeq mI$$

Comment: Im pretty sure they mean: $A ⪰ B$ if $A-B ⪰ 0$, i.e $A-B$ is a positive definite operator

Comment: Get it, Thanks. I'm sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: It's definitely not a stupid question :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Tom Ariel's answer, $A \succeq B$ means $A-B$ is a positive **semidefinite** operator. In matrix analysis literature, it is also called Löwner partial ordering on the symmetric matrices $\mathbb{S}^n$.

$A \succeq B$ if and only if $A-B\in \mathbb{S}^n_{+}$, where $\mathbb{S}^n_{+}$ is the positive semidefinite cone.